# Printing from MAP in JAVA

Tags: java, mapping

I want to print some data that I've passed to map from a text file. However, when I print the data, program prints the lines twice. Is there any way to fix it? I just want to print the data in an exact way, no duplicates.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadToHashmap {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Documents and Settings\\stajn\\Desktop\\Cache_Son\\Cache\\Testing.txt"));




         if (bufferedReader != null) {
            String line;


         while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
             String parts[] = line.split("\n");
             map.put(parts[0],parts[0]); 


            }

            bufferedReader.close();


            Iterator iterator = map.keySet().iterator();  

        while (iterator.hasNext()) 
    {  
        String key = iterator.next().toString();  
        String value = map.get(key).toString();  

        System.out.println(key + " " + value);  
    }  
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting in map  like

```
 map.put(parts[0],parts[0]);
```

So here Key and value are same.When you print

```
 System.out.println(key + " " + value);
```

Both will  print the same.

Do you need ?

```
 System.out.println("value=" + value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the line both in the KEY like in the VALUE of the MAP.

In your code you are printing KEY and VALUE so you are duplicating the line

You can print only the values content on a map with:

```
Iterator iterator = map.values().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {   

    System.out.println(iterator.next());  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some other serious problems:

When using `bufferedReader.readLine()` your String will never contain a newline-character so your split() will do nothing and parts[] will always be a length-1-array.

As for printing the same value twice see the other answers...